# Executing git-hooks on windows errors out

Tags: regex, windows, git, githooks, git-bash

So,

I have written a simple git-hooks for pre-push which works just fine on Linux or Mac, but doesn't work on Windows.

Script:
Tries to match the commit message with a regular expression, and should return 0 if matches or else exit.

Based on the articles I read, they say that the hook should just work.

Command:

```
if [[ "$message" =~ "$regular_expression" ]];
```

Error:

```
.git/hooks/pre-push: line 6: conditional binary operator expected
.git/hooks/pre-push: line 6: syntax error near `=~'
.git/hooks/pre-push: line 6: `  if [[ "$message" =~ "$regular_expression" ]]; then'
```

So apparently it seems to be failing on "[[" and "]]".

Now I have also tried removing the double brackets and keep only one.

Command:

```
if [ "$message" =~ "$regular_expression" ];
```

*Error:*

```
.git/hooks/pre-push: line 6: [: =~: binary operator expected
This message is flawed: TRY-1 Sample
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue ?

Comment: What is the script type? bash? sha? zsh etc. looks like its not complaint with your windows environament. What is your git environment? msysGit? git-scm?

Comment: Could you start your script with `#!/bin/bash`? (and see if the error persists)

Comment: Already tried /bin/bash but executing on windows is the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `=~` construct in bash conditional expressions is not supported in the version of bash shipped with Git for Windows. It looks like the `=~` operator was introduced in bash 3.0 but while Git for Windows is using bash 3.1 it seems to be missing this operator.

Possibly `$(echo $message | grep "$regexp")` will work as a substitute. eg:

```
$ bash -c '[[ "hello" =~ "^h" ]]'
bash: -c: line 0: conditional binary operator expected
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near `=~'
bash: -c: line 0: `[[ "hello" =~ "^h" ]]'

$ bash -c '[ $(echo hello | grep "^h") ] && echo matched || echo nomatch'
matched
```

**Update**

Here is an example script that works to match something similar using the Git for Windows bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# grep returns 0 on matching something, 1 whn it fails to match
msg='TEST-111 Sample'
re='([A-Z]{2,8}-[0-9]{1,4}[[:space:]])+[A-Za-z0-9]+[[:space:]]*[A-Za-z0-9]+$'
rx='^([A-Z]{2,8}-[0-9]{1,4})[[:space:]][[:alnum:]]+$'

echo $msg | grep -qE "$rx"
[ $? = 0 ] && echo matched || echo nomatch
```

This script returns matched for the sample phrase using the second regular expression. Its not really clear what the original expression is attempting to match up -- looks like multiple words so I'm not sure why you don't just match `.*$`. However, this shows a way to try out the regexp. Note: we are using extended regular expressions (`[[:space:]]`) so we have to use `grep -E`. Also we have to take some care about quoting as `$` is being used in the regexp.

Comment: Here is the worrying part:
`message="TEST-111 Sample"`
`regex="([A-Z]{2,8}-[0-9]{1,4}[[:space:]])+[A-Za-z0-9]+[[:space:]]*[A-Za-z0-9]+$"`
`bash -c '[ $(echo "$message" | grep "$regex") ] && echo matched || echo nomatch'` returns nomatch
`bash -c '[[ "$commit_message" =~ $regex ]] && echo matched || echo nomatch'` returns matched

Comment: Extended the answer to cover this I hope.

Comment: Hey @patthoyts, what if the msg changes from "TEST-111 Sample" to "TEST-111 Sample Order requested by me" ? Meaning adding multiple words.  In that case [[:alnum:]]+ doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Depends. Do you actually need to capture that? If you're just matching the line then ignore the end parts. Your question never stated much about what you are trying to do nor what variety of input you might have. I'd loose the final [[:alnum:]]+$ unless you actually care whats there or are mismatching other input with only the front part of the regex.

Comment: I think I got my answer: 
`regex="^([A-Z]{2,8}-[0-9]{1,4}[[:space:]])+([[:alnum:]][[:space:]]*)+$"`